# Azure Blob Storage .uploadStream() not uploading more than 42 bytes

Tags: node.js, azure

I am trying to upload a video from my azure VM to azure blob storage with @azure/storage-blob and using .uploadStream(), but it is not uploading more than 42 bytes

```
progress { loadedBytes: 42 }
```

even though the file is 5.7 kb

```
-rw-r--r--  1 root      root      5.7K Oct 11 10:33 345009243
```

My upload code is like this

```
 const { BlobServiceClient, StorageSharedKeyCredential } = require("@azure/storage-blob");
    const dotenv = require('dotenv');
    const getStream = require('into-stream');
    //import getStream from 'into-stream'
    dotenv.config();
    
    const account = process.env.STORAGE_ACCOUNT;
    const accountKey = process.env.ACCOUNT_KEY;
    
    const sharedKeyCredential = new StorageSharedKeyCredential(account, accountKey);
    const blobServiceClient = new BlobServiceClient(
        `https://${account}.blob.core.windows.net`,sharedKeyCredential
    );
    
    const containerName = process.env.CONTAINER_NAME;
    
    const uploadFile = async(filePath,filename) => {
        const containerClient = blobServiceClient.getContainerClient(containerName);
        const blobName = "vimeoVedio" + new Date().getTime();
        const blockBlobClient = containerClient.getBlockBlobClient(blobName);
        const buffer = Buffer.from(filePath);
        const stream = getStream(buffer);
        const streamLenght = (1 * 1024 * 1024) / 2;
        const uploadBlobResponse = await blockBlobClient.uploadStream(stream,streamLenght, 400, {
            // abortSignal: AbortController.timeout(30 * 60 * 1000), // Abort uploading with timeout in 30mins
            onProgress: (ev) => {console.log("progress", ev)},
            blobHTTPHeaders: {blobContentType: filename.mimeType}
          });
        return Promise.resolve(`Upload block blob ${blobName} successfully`, uploadBlobResponse.requestId);
    }
    
    module.exports = {uploadFile}
```

I tried this upload with multiple different files with different file sizes but it still is only uploading 42 bytes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the issue is in this line of code:

```
const buffer = Buffer.from(filePath);
```

What you are doing here is creating a buffer from a string representing the file path (`e.g. C:\temp\myfile.txt`) instead of the actual file contents.

You would want to use [`fs`](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html) module and read the contents of the file using something like [`fs.readFile(path[, options], callback)`](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fsreadfilepath-options-callback) or [`fs.readFileSync(path\[, options\])`](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fsreadfilesyncpath-options). Once you do that, you should be able to upload the file properly.